# mysqli bind_param don't work php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm learning `mysqli_`. If I run the query without the bind_param it works, but if I add the `bind_param` my query stops working.

This is my code:

```
// Make a connection to database.
$user = 'test';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `user` = ?";
$querySelect = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$querySelect->bind_param('s', $user);
$querySelect->execute();
echo 'N: '.$querySelect->num_rows.'<br>'; // Got 0, but the correct result is 1.
```

**ERROR:**

> Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Comment: Errors, please. "Not working" is not a useful bit of information. You may want to [enable exceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578243/turning-query-errors-to-exceptions-in-mysqli) to have errors bubbled up.

Comment: That call isn't shown in this code, so you'll have to track it down.

Comment: You should assign the execute method to a variable and work with this

Comment: Error added in question

Comment: Add `var_dump($querySelect);` before the call to `bind_param`. My guess is that the `prepare` statement is failing. Per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php): _"`mysqli_prepare()` returns a statement object or `FALSE` if an error occurred."_

Comment: Got `object(mysqli_stmt)#2 (0) { }` i'm on php 5.2

Comment: When you are using PDO you should use `$querySelect->bindParam('s', $user);`.

Comment: i'm using `mysqli`

Answer (score 2):

I guess this line returns false:

```
$querySelect = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
```

try to do:

```
var_dump($querySelect);
```

in order to be sure. If return false, that means something wrong with getting data user from database (wrong table, connection, table column, ...)

but this sql is also strange:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `user` = ?";
```

maybe you wanted to write:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `user_id` = ?";
```

so, user_id instead of user or maybe only id, depends on the name of you primary key